# Showing a fragment over a viewpager

Tags: android

I have a `ViewPager` with 3 sliding `fragments`. Each of the `fragment` has `listview` which contains some images. I'm trying to show a new `fragment` over the viewpager (like an activity) when one of the images in the `listview` is clicked and also have the ability to navigate back to the viewpager when back button is pressed.

My code for the `listview` onClick which is inside the fragment is as follows(for testing, I'm using `onClick` on the entire `listview` and not the images)

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Clicked");
            ItemDetailFragment fragment = ItemDetailFragment.newInstance("ab","cd");
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.containerr,fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
});
```

The log statement prints out fine, but the fragment doesn't show up.

Here's my activity which has the `viewpager`

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WithActionBar">

    <com.firstapp.myapplication.CustomViews.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/containerr">
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please help.

Also, in the examples in android docs, any interaction in a fragment which leads to a fragment transaction is first passed to the parent activity which handles adding or replacing a new fragment. I am handling that here in the fragment itself. Which one is the correct way and what is the difference between the two methods?

**EDIT** : I need to add fragment over the viewPager and not to it. It's like having a new screen come up on clicking an element inside the viewpager's fragment.

Thanks!

Comment: If you need "over the viewpager " ,  best thing you can do is, start a new activity and attached the ItemDetail fragment into it. Thats the recommended way instead of attaching fragment into viewpager .

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. I am not trying to attach the `fragment` to the `viewpager` but to the parent activity which has the view pager.

Comment: you mean that ItemDetail fragment is one of 3 sliding fragments ?

Comment: No. ItemDetail fragment is the new fragment which is supposed to show up over the viewpager.

Comment: Thats what i am suggesting ,  you can create a new activity and attach the ItemDetail  fragment into it . Or else if you add the ItemDetail into view pager, users can swipe and view it even without clicking a particular list item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by adding the `viewpager` in a `fragment`(instead of having it directly in my `activity` itself).

My activity now is

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and I moved the previous activity layout (mentioned in the question) to a `ViewPagerFragment`

Now in my activity's `onCreate` I do

```
ViewPagerFragment viewPagerFragment = new ViewPagerFragment();

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.fragment_container, viewPagerFragment)
        .commit();
```

and for showing a new `fragment` over the viewpager on clicking an item inside the viewpager's fragment, I do

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(null);
    }
});
```

The listener is an interface implemented in the parent activity as follows

```
@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
    ItemDetailFragment itemDetailFragment = ItemDetailFragment.newInstance("ab","cd");
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container,itemDetailFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

I implemented this via the listener interface because as per the [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

> > All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

And it works now! :D

Comment: can you please share xml file. how you add viewpager to fragment?

Answer (score -1):

**Initialize your fragment in Activity class and add them to viewpager like below**

```
List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();
pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
```

**Add fragments to your viewpager**

```
private List<Fragment> getFragments() {

    List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    fList.add(Fragment1.newInstance());
    fList.add(Fragment2.newInstance());
    fList.add(Fragment3.newInstance());

    return fList;
}

/********************** Fragment Page adapter *************************/
private class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

And create your fragment classes and handle the listview inside those class

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this doesn't let me add Fragment over the ViewPager but instead "to the" viewPager.

Comment: you can use another fragment and to the main layout and set its view to visible and gone when user click on list.